# Expand LOGBOOK on 2nd Tab press? (hook for 2nd org-cycle?)

Tags: org-mode, hooks, cycling

In org-mode..

I store lots of state-change messages and timing info in the `LOGBOOK` drawer.

Most of the time, I don't look into the `LOGBOOK` drawer, but once in a while when following up on a pending task, I peek into the `LOGBOOK` drawer to see my note.

I'm looking for a quick-way to expand the drawer using TAB on the head-line. 
Currently, 1st tab expands the entry, 2nd tab expands entry + subentry but not the `LOGBOOK` drawer.

Ideally, I'd like to:

1. First tab expands the entry,
2. Second tab expands sub-headings **including `LOGBOOK`** drawer (but not `PROPERTIES` or other drawers).

So I'm trying to tie in a function into the `org-cycle-hook`, but I have an issue:

```el
(defun my/expand-logbook-drawer ()
 "Expand the closest logbook drawer"
 (interactive)
 (search-forward ":LOGBOOK:")
 (org-cycle)
)

(add-hook 'org-cycle-hook
  (lambda (my/var/curr-state)
    (interactive)
    (message "State changed")
    (when (= my/var/curr-state "all")   ;This comparison doesn't work, error: wrong argument, number-or-marker-p
      (my/expand-logbook-drawer)
    )
  )
)
```

It seems my comparison function doesn't work. Thoughts?

Note, the org-mode-cycle docu is [here](http://orgmode.org/worg/doc.html#outline-container-orgtbl-mode-off-hook)

Comment: `=` is for comparing numbers, you probably want `string-equal` or just `equal`.

Comment: I treid string-equal, but I get stringpq errors ...?

Comment: Then it means that `my/var/curr-state` isn't a string. A simple way to debug it is to put a `(message "my/var/curr-state: %s" my/var/curr-state)` before the offending line and after this hook fires, look into the `*Messages*` buffer.

Comment: I recommend taking a look at the function `org-cycle-internal-local` and insert your function at the appropriate section -- e.g., if you want your function to run when `"CHILDREN"` are exposed, then insert your function at that section of the code.  You can create a new function to replace `org-cycle-internal-local`, by having it evaluated after `org.el` is required -- I believe the current version of Emacs loads the library  on startup, so you can probably just drop your new `org-cycle-internal-local` into your `.emacs` file and away you go.  I have not attempted to debug your proposed code.